# Why not a simple division in this case?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, arithmetic

`n` represents total number of persons.
`max` represents the maximum number of persons by department.

To know the accepted number of persons by department, I would do:

```
personsPerDepartment = n / max
```

However, I read on a programming book:

```
personsPerDepartment = (n + (max - 1)) / max
```

I don't figure out what this formula means.
Is it a tip to round the result?
Indeed, it would be equals to:

```
n / max + (max - 1) / max  =  n / max + ~1
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not immediately clear what you're trying to do here, but I suppose it is something like

> If you have to distribute $n$ persons across departments, and each department can take at most $\mathit{max}$ of them, then how many departments do you need to involve?

Suppose you have $n=5$ and $\mathit{max}=4$. Obviously you need two departments for that. However if you simply divide $5$ by $4$, you get $1.25$, which is a quite strange number of departments.

So what you want to do is *round the result of the division **upwards** to the nearest integer* if it is not already an integer.

Most programming languages don't do that when you divide two integers and the result doesn't come out even. Instead they round *down* (actually, towards $0$). The alternative calculation
$$ (a+b-1)/b $$
is just a common trick to get the round-UP behavior when dividing $a$ by $b$, when all you have is a division operator that rounds down, without involving floating point which is seen as inefficient.

Adding $b-1$ to the numerator will change the numbers in the interval $5
\ldots 8$ (which are the ones you *want* to produce 2 departments) into the interval $8\ldots 11$ (which are what *actually* produce a result of $2$ departments with the division operator you have to work with). And similarly for all of the other possible intervals.

Comment: That's exactly what I though :) 
May you read the comment I write on the other answer?

Comment: Your last paragraph is great. Thanks a lot, I get it.

Comment: "into the interval 8…11" => isn't it 7..11? oO

Comment: @Mik378: No, it's the numbers 8, 9, 10, and 11. You wouldn't get the right result for 7 because $7/4=1.75$ which rounds down to $1$, and we're interested in the values that give $2$. But it should have been $5\ldots 8$ rather than $4\ldots 8$ -- now fixed.

Comment: Yes, now it's perfectly understandable :)  (You've just made a typo: 55 instead of 5 ;) )

Answer (score 2):

When using [*integer division*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html), the formula `(n + (max - 1)) / max` is equivalent to $\Big\lceil\frac{n}{\max}\Big\rceil$.

These brackets mean [*ceiling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), or in your words: "it is a tip to round the result **upwards**".

Comment: what does this brackets mean?

Comment: Oh that's what I though. 
But I imagined a case where n / max gives 4.2 and max - 1 / max gives 0.7 .. result would be 4.9 => not ceiled.  Is it a case impossible to obtain with this formula?

Comment: @Mik378: thew formula you've stated is not `(max-1)/max`, it is `(n+max-1)/max`.

Comment: Yes, but I based my comment on the developped formula: 
`n / max + (max - 1) / max`  where  `n / max` would give `4.2` and `max - 1 / max` would give `0.7`.

Comment: @Mik378: Sorry, I've updated my answer. The division as you've mentioned is most likely *integer division* on a computer program.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but how to be sure in EVERY case that the formula would give a ceiled result.

Comment: @Mik378: Adding `max-1` to `n` ensures that you get the ceiling of dividing `n` by `max`.